# Counter variable for actionevent

Tags: java, swing, variables, jbutton

I have an int variable that is set a certain value, when a JButton is clicked on the GUI the buttons visibility is set to false, and the counter variable should decrease by one. Once it hits 0 an if statement is executed. The problem is the counter variable keeps getting reset everytime I click a button. This is my code

```
public int someMethod(){
    intVar= 3;
    return intVar;
}

public void anotherMethod(){
    intVar--;
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
if (someCondition){
            clickedButton.setVisible(false);
            anotherMethod();
            if (someMethod()==0){
  //Do something
  }
```

Comment: `The problem is the counter variable keeps getting reset everytime ` Why does your `someMethod()` always reset the variable to 3?

Comment: `so intVar really equals myarraylist.size().` - then you should be using myArrayList.size() and get rid of the variable. There is no need for you to keep duplicate information. It causes problems as you can see.

Comment: It works as a counter though, I need to store what number its at so i can use the if statement I posted a pastebin of my actual code below

Comment: The ArrayList method is your counter. Just invoke the method every time you want to check how many items are in the ArrayList.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `someMethod()` resets the counter to 3. Thus it will **always** return `3`. Thus your `if` block will never be executed.

`someMethod()` is logically equivalent to the following, barring any concurrency shenanigans:

```
public int someMethod() {
    intVar = 3;
    return 3;
}
```

Thus your `actionPerformed(...)` is logically equivalent to the following (ibid):

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (someCondition){
        clickedButton.setVisible(false);
        anotherMethod();
        if (3==0){
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

If the counter should just decrease, and the if block should be executed when `intVar == 0` just use the intVar directly in your comparison:

```
public int anotherMethod(){
    return --intVar;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (someCondition){
        clickedButton.setVisible(false);
        anotherMethod();
        if (intVar==0){
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Or, remove the assignment from `someMethod()`:

```
public int someMethod() {
    return intVar;
}
```

Or, get rid of `someMethod()` call here and return the updated counter value from 'anotherMethod()' to change code to:

```
public int anotherMethod(){
    return intVar--;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (someCondition){
        clickedButton.setVisible(false);
        if (anotherMethod()==0){
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because in method `someMethod()` you always end up resetting the variable to 3. Instantiate the variable outside the method only once.

Another interesting fact (not related to this), Integers from `-127 to +128` are stored in the integer pool (cached) and any reference to value in the range is done to object in pool. (Applicable for Integer only and not ints)

Comment: I believe that the integer pool information is for Integer objects only and not ints, and so does not apply to this application. 1+ for the other piece of information though.

Comment: I actually have another method, where inside that method it reads data from another class,it takes an array size.so intVar really equals  myarraylist.size(). When i instantitae it outside a method and use it inside an if statement i get null pointer

Comment: Your second paragraph has no connection to anything in the question. There was no question about memory consumption, and there is no reason to assume that any of the variables in that code is of type `Integer` rather than `int`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks for correcting me here.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I did mention that it was not related to this question and I was just trying to share the info. Not sure why it hurts (corrected info)

Comment: @ugCode: then it's time to debug that NullPointer. Search this site for how to do that. Edit: look here: [NullPointerExceptions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510).

Comment: Answers should be just that: answers. They should not contain information that is irrelevant to the question. Share that information in answers to questions about the `Integer` type when the information is relevant. Irrelevant information is confusing, may damage the ability to search for the answer properly, and is not helpful.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Never looked at it from that perspective but would agree to it till some extent. Thanks :)